# No data is inserted into my table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a simpe table:

```
Users
UserID     Guid   doesnt allow null
Avatar     image  allows null
Reputation int    allows null
```

I used the following statement:

```
string insertCommand = "INSERT INTO Users (UserID) VALUES" +""+ "('"+UsersIdentityToinsert+"')";
```

UsersIdentityToinsert(this value is a Guid, I checked its value, it isn't null).

There were no exceptions thrown. As soon as the user presses the login button, he is transfered to another page, and his record is inserted. 
I followed with the debugging that that statement is executed.

When I return to my server explorer in Visual Studio 2010 and click refresh the Users table is empty. Why is that?

Connection string

```
<add name="YourGuruDB" connectionString="Data Source=DIMA-00AA1DA557;Initial Catalog=model;Integrated Security=True"/>
```

i retrieve it from config into the code:

```
WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourGuruDB"].ConnectionString;
```

Added:

```
    public static void InsertUsers(Guid UsersIDentity)
{
    SqlConnection sqlConnect = getSqlConnection();
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(RegisterAdo.insertCommand(UsersIDentity), sqlConnect);//insert command method returns the insert statement described above
    try
    {
        sqlConnect.Open();
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
    catch (Exception x)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/ErrorPage.aspx?Error=" + WRITE_ERROR);

    }
    finally
    {
        sqlConnect.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code that executes this?  Can you post that?

Comment: Hi, but do you have an open connection to the db? Cheers, Darren

Comment: What do u mean an open connection..i updated my question details with the connection string

Comment: The code is a bit long, but i just followed the code the way it was described in the book, every statement gets executed. i checked with the debug mode too

Comment: Do you actually have a line of code that reads something like SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString)???

Comment: I have got all that. If i didnt an exception would be thrown. I added some details above

Comment: You have not shown the code where the SQL command actually gets executed. See my answer below for an example of what that should look like. You need a SqlCommand object and to use its ExecuteNonQuery method somewhere. You have not shown that, which makes me wonder if you are actually calling it.

Comment: getSqlConnection(); ==that method i described above returns the connection string YourGuruDB

Comment: Given the code you had previously, all I saw was some string assignment, that wouldn't have thrown an exception and it wouldn't have inserted anything in the database either.

Comment: what do you think of the code that i edited now!?!? (in the answer above).. i think the code is the most basic as it can be with executing an insert command. But the GUID value wont go into the database. Its value is null

Comment: Incidentally, why are you putting it in a system database ("Initial Catalog=model")?. Why didn't you create a specific database for your program?

Comment: I think i used he default settings, I use windows authentication for that database. I read that windows authentication is more secure than sql authentication. But whats wrong with that?

Comment: I  am thinking of using something like DataAdapter that allows you to parameterise your variables.. But that DataAdapter works with Dataset

Comment: Actually, correction, my database wont insert anything into the database, i tried to insert the value of 1 into my Reputation column in the same User table. nothing was inserted :(

Comment: You should **NEVER** concatenate together your SQL statements! This leads to [SQL injection attacks](http://xkcd.com/327/) ! Avoid this at all costs - use **parametrized queries** instead - they're better for performance, too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using

```
"INSERT INTO Users (UserID) VALUES" +""+ "('"+UsersIdentityToinsert+"')";
```

use this:

```
"INSERT INTO Users (UserID) VALUES" +""+ "(CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, '"+UsersIdentityToinsert+"'))";
```

And you really should use a prepared Statement instead of concatenating the sql.

What about the DB-connection? Did you run any successfull statements so far? Try a simple select.

Comment: I tested the connection, and run the select statement described above. what des the convert method do?

Comment: @Matrix001 You try to insert a GUID as a string which might work but can fail sometimes. The convert converts the string-GUID into a real GUID.

Comment: How do i do that? the insert statement must be a string :( ..may be you are saying that i might use an object as a type..but then, i have to convert it to string in the end, cause the constructor SQLcommand takes two parameters (string connectionString, SQLconnection connection)

Comment: @Matrix001 No just replace your code with mine. In your statement you have 'yourguid' and you have to replace it with the second line I posted. I clearify it in my answer. That should do the trick.

Comment: oooh, no, your line didnt throw an exception, but it didnt insert anything. It simply wont insert, i tried to insert to a "Reputation" field (int) in the "Users" table.. it wont even insert a simple int. What else could it be ? the connection string?

Comment: It actually inserted one value now. But doesnt seem to work if i have more than one person login in..hmmm

Comment: Does 'more than one person' mean different users or the same user multiple times? Could be a problem with connection limits. Did you create your table in a separate database or are you really working on 'model'?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
"INSERT INTO Users (UserID) VALUES ('"+UsersIdentityToinsert+"')";
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things to check

- Are you connected to the right database?
- Is the code that executes this SQL Statement actually working. You don't show that code. I'd be expecting a `ExecuteNonQuery()` on a `SqlCommand` object somewhere.
- Do you actually open a connection to a database? Or is the connection string just in the config without being used anywhere in your code?

Also, your code is susceptible to a SQL Injection attack. You should use a parameterised query to prevent that. This [article on SQL Injection Attacks](http://colinmackay.co.uk/blog/2005/04/23/sql-injection-attacks-and-some-tips-on-how-to-prevent-them/) will help you with how to write that.

You also have missing code which I'd expect to see. Something along the lines of this:

```
string insertCommand = "INSERT INTO Users (UserID) VALUES" 
    +""+ "('"+UsersIdentityToinsert+"')";
string cs = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourGuruDB"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertCommand, conn);
conn.Open();
cmd.ExexuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```